# Is there an emotion that encapsulates a mixture of disbelief, anger, and hatred?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, emotions

For all the words I know, I can't seem to find the right word for this strange emotion. Some words I have tried come up short in one way or another. *Confusion* lacks the underlying hatred, *annoyance* ignores the triggering bafflement, *skepticism* is to forward to properly describe the abhorrent serenity caused by this mixture of emotions.

I tried looking on Google and several other sites for some synonyms for each of them, but my results kept coming up short. Even my 'Better-words-for-authors' guides proved insufficient. I'm starting to think there might not even be a single word in the English lexicon for this emotional mixture that is hatred and anger caused by disbelief.

Example of how it could be used:

> He couldn't help but feel [blank], had the youtuber really sunken below rock bottom.

*- or -*

> [blank] began to well up inside of her. The others had resorted to Orwellian new speak to justify their problematic behavior.

Comment: Does this word suffice the sentiment you are trying to encapsulate - *Outrage*?

Comment: Outrage is a good word, but it's too active for the emotion I'm trying to convey.

Comment: *Indignance* means a righteous anger after someone has been wronged. This word is softer and has a moral tinge to it. Hatred emotion may be missing here though. May be that helps!

Comment: Downvoted for the really poor contextual examples given in the question.

Comment: The word might indeed be indignance. So if its posted as a answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: 'Apoplectic' means 'extremely enraged' (M-W uses the grading). In such a state, disbelief of what has caused such rage, and rancour, are likely. // 'Dumbfounded' is a part-hypernym, but doesn't have to include rancour.

Comment: Ambivalent.....

Comment: @TimR you may not like the given examples but that is not a valid reason for downvoting (most unkind to a new user, contrary to site Code of Conduct).  Like them or not, they exemplify the circumstances of the question. Please read the site code and guidelines again before indulging in such unjustifiable negativity. I have compensated for your downvote and suggest that you retract it.

Comment: @Anton The examples provided very little context.  It's not a matter of my not "liking" them. I gave my reason for downvoting (which many downvoters do not do) and that comment has given OP a chance to rectify the situation. If OP improves the examples, I will remove the downvote.  OP rejected the word **outrage** which clearly fits the title of the question, as being too "active". OP should provide some examples then, that show the passivity of the emotion.

Answer (score 3):

We often get posts on this forum for "one word" that expresses some complex idea. Like, "What is one word that means a tall, bald man wearing a blue shirt who likes to ride motorcycles?" Okay, I'm being deliberately silly. But the simple answer is, In English, at least, if you want to express a complex idea, you normally need to use multiple words.

I see you've gotten several suggestions but I'd quibble with all of them meaning exactly the combination of three emotions that you ask for.

Like I see someone suggested "indignant". I understand that to include anger. But it's hazy if it would imply hatred, and I don't see it incorporating disbelief at all. Like, I wouldn't consider it at all jarring if someone said, "When Bob called me fat, I was indignant. It's true that I'm fat, but it's very rude to point it out like that with no cause." That is, you can be indignant about something you believe to be 100% true.

You gave several examples yourself that fall into the same category. That is, include one or two of these emotions but not the others. Like "skeptical" indicates a mild form of disbelief -- you're not saying it's false, just that you're not convinced it's true. But one can be skeptical without being angry or hateful at all. If a girl said I was handsome, I know I'm not, so you could say I'd be skeptical, but I probably wouldn't be angry or hateful. (Depending on the circumstances, I might be pleased that she was trying to be nice to me. I might feel sorry for her obviously poor eyesight. I might be suspicious that she was trying to flatter me to get something from me. Etc.)

If you want to say that someone felt a combination of these three emotions, I think you need to just use those three words.

Comment: This seems like it belongs in [meta] as something we can link to more generally for `single-word-request` questions.

Comment: +1. But what's your quibble with **outrage**? Seems to me it fires on all three cylinders,  disbelief, anger, and hatred.  Outrage can lead to action, often rash action, but not always. Why OP rejected it as "too active" is unclear.

Comment: @timr thefreedictionary.com defines "outrage" as "resentful anger aroused by a violent or offensive act". So it clearly involves anger. I don't see that it necessarily involves hatred. I may be "outraged" that my 6 year old broke my laptop, but I wouldn't hate him. And I don't see how it involves disbelief at all. I am outraged at Nazi atrocities and slavery, precisely because I absolutely believe that they really happened.I agree that the statement about it being "too active" is curious and probably not relevant, but I would reject it on other grounds.

Comment: @Jay Dictionary definitions only take you so far.  People feel outrage when their country or village is attacked, say; it can begin as disbelief that this is actually happening to them, and that disbelief can become indignation, which can turn into anger and then rage, culminating in a seething hatred for the attackers.

Comment: @timr I agree that dictionary definitions can be incomplete or misleading. As to the rest of your post, I guess we have to ask what the OP meant by "disbelief". When someone says "I don't believe this is happening", they rarely mean that literally. I mean, they don't mean "I think this attack is a hallucination or a trick". They mean that in a very metaphorical sense. They don't really not believe it, they just think it is, well, outrageous. I took the OP to mean "disbelief" literally: "I think this person is lying or mistaken when he says this."

Comment: To say, "I can think of an example where anger would be accompanied by hatred and disbelief" ... Sure. That's the premise of the question. But that doesn't mean that anger is ALWAYS accompanied by hatred and disbelief, nor that any given word that implies anger must also imply hatred and disbelief.

Answer (score 0):

The word which encapsulates the sentiment of anger and disbelief could very well be **indignant**. Here is the [dictionary.com reference](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/indignant) to it.

The link says:

> feeling, characterized by, or expressing strong displeasure at something considered unjust, offensive, insulting, or base: indignant remarks; an indignant expression on his face.

An example from the recent news [item](https://www.mediaite.com/news/maggie-haberman-says-trump-and-trumpworld-angry-and-indignant-about-explosive-new-indictment/):

> Maggie Haberman Says Trump and Trumpworld Angry and ‘Indignant’ About Explosive New Indictment

Comment: I thought you hit the nail on the head with **outrage**.

Comment: Well, OP told me that *indignant* suits his requirements more, as can be seen in the comments. He asked me to post *indignant* as the answer. That’s why I did that.